# How to create an RS485-compatible line driver with an adjustable slew rate?

Tags: rs485, transmitter, transceiver, slew-rate

I need to make an RS485 compatible line driver, capable of 12Mbit/s with fast slew rate, but with the capability to reduce the slew rate to about 50ns rise/fall time when operating at lower bitrates.

The line driver must support all normal RS485 features:

- Short circuit protected;
- Tristate with a wide common mode range;
- Low bus loading during tristate.

I can't find any standard RS485 transceivers with this kind of adjustable slew rate capability.
Building it from discrete transistors would probably be possible, but is not exactly ideal.

Is there another way?

Comment: I can imagine a transciever that uses an external capacitor to set the slew rate, you can then switch different capacitances.

Comment: Yes, or an external resistor.. But I have not been able to find any such transceiver.

Comment: We have used both resistors ( to provide a defined resistance) and capacitors to control the slew rate on a RS-485 interface, which was needed to ameliorate the effects of stubs on a multi-drop interface.  But these components were fixed values and part of the PCB design.  Their values were not dynamically adjustable.

Comment: This is dangerously close to a product recommendation, but a LTC2865
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2862345fc.pdf
has a logic-selectable 250kbps slew rate-limited mode.

Comment: Vir: I am aware of that one, but its low slew rate mode is too slow for what I need. I need a slew rate around 50ns or so.

Comment: How about using a fully differential amplifier (differential outputs) with programmable resistor (and fixed cap) in the feedback path for controlled slew rate? The op-amp needs to be both high bandwidth and strong driving output, so choosing the right chip is important.

Comment: icodeolenty: I don't think a differential amplifier can tristate it's outputs? And if it could, it would not tolerate a large enough common mode range.